# Date picker on product page - Shopify

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to get my date picker on my product page to work.

Right now I'm using this code and it's working fine. But it does not take the picked date data with it. So I can't see it in the order or on the cart page.

Its working if I have the date picker on the cart page, but because I only need the date picker on certain products. So I have made a separate product page to theese products.

Code

```
{{ '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" defer="defer"></script>

<div style="width:300px; display:inline-block;">
  <p>
    <label for="date">Vælg leveringsdato:</label>
    <input id="date" type="text" name="attributes[date]" value="{{ product_form_id }}" />
  </p>
</div>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
      if (window.jQuery) {
        let $ = window.jQuery;
        
        $(function() {
          $("#date").datepicker({
          minDate: +1,
          maxDate: '+2M',
          beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
          dayNamesMin: [ "Søn", "Man", "Tir", "Ons", "Tors", "Fre", "Lør" ],
          monthNames: [ "Januar", "Februar", "Marts", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", 
                       "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December" ]
            
        });
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow a different pattern if I were you. Instead of using cart attributes, I would use product **line item properties**. Then you get your date per product. Imagine one customer wanting two products, each with a date? Your attribute idea will fail there!

You can follow many tutorials on line item properties, and there are even generator pages that make all the code for you. Just substitute your date picker outputs as the inputs to the line item properties, and you'll see orders with correct dates selected by the customer, in your orders.

Comment: Where do I use Cart attributes?

I need to change it, so it works on the product page instead of the cart page. But it dosent take the picked date data to the order

Comment: Look up Shopify and Line Item Properties. I answered you. All you need is there.